# Logstash multiple scheduled piplines

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-configuration

So Im want to configure multiple logstash .conf files (pipelines) with different schedule configuration for example in have file1.conf with is configuration :

*file1.conf*

```
   input {
  jdbc { jdbc_connection_string=>'jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:3306/<databasename>'
    # The user we wish to execute our statement as
    jdbc_user => '****'
    jdbc_password => '*****'
    # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
    jdbc_driver_library => 'mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.jar'
    jdbc_driver_class => 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'

    schedule => "30 * * * *"
    # our query

   statement => "select *  from elasticsync2 "

    }
filter {  

  grok  {
    match => {"date" => ["%{DATE:date_format}"]}
 
  }
} 

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }

  elasticsearch {
  hosts => ['https://x.x.x.x:9200/','https://x.x.x.x:9200/']
  index => '******'
  user => "*********"
  password => "*************"
  cacert => "./certs/ca.crt"
  ssl_certificate_verification => true

  document_type => "data"
  }
}
```

*the second pipeline*

*file2.conf*

```
      input {
  jdbc { jdbc_connection_string=>'jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:3306/<databasename>'
    # The user we wish to execute our statement as
    jdbc_user => '****'
    jdbc_password => '*****'
    # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
    jdbc_driver_library => 'mysql-connector-java-5.1.49.jar'
    jdbc_driver_class => 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'

    schedule => "20 * * * *"
    # our query

   statement => "select *  from elasticsync "

    }
filter {  

  grok  {
    match => {"date" => ["%{DATE:date_format}"]}
 
  }
} 

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }

  elasticsearch {
  hosts => ['https://x.x.x.x:9200/','https://x.x.x.x:9200/']
  index => '******'
  user => "*********"
  password => "*************"
  cacert => "./certs/ca.crt"
  ssl_certificate_verification => true

  document_type => "data"
  }
}
```

*piplines.yml*

```
- pipeline.id: first-pip
  path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/file1.conf"
  queue.type: persisted
- pipeline.id: second-pip
  path.config: "/etc/logstash/conf.d/file2.conf"
```

logstash logs

```
 [2022-01-13T20:44:21,652][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][second-pip] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["https://x.x.x.x:9200/", "https://x.x.x.x:9200/"]}
[2022-01-13T20:44:21,656][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][first-pip] New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["https://x.x.x.x:9200/", "https://x.x.x.x:9200/"]}
[2022-01-13T20:44:22,647][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][first-pip] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[https://logstash_writer:xxxxxx@x.x.x.x:9200/, https://logstash_writer:xxxxxx@x.x.x.x:9200/]}}
[2022-01-13T20:44:22,647][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][second-pip] Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>[https://logstash_writer:xxxxxx@x.x.x.x:9200/, https://logstash_writer:xxxxxx@x.x.x.x:9200/]}}
[2022-01-13T20:44:23,811][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][second-pip] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"https://logstash_writer:xxxxxx@x.x.x.x:9200/"}
[2022-01-13T20:44:23,812][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][first-pip] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"https://logstash_writer:xxxxxx@x.x.x.x:9200/"}
[2022-01-13T20:44:23,938][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][second-pip] Elasticsearch version determined (7.14.0) {:es_version=>7}
[2022-01-13T20:44:23,946][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][second-pip] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
[2022-01-13T20:44:23,938][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][first-pip] Elasticsearch version determined (7.14.0) {:es_version=>7}
[2022-01-13T20:44:23,951][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][first-pip] Detected a 6.x and above cluster: the `type` event field won't be used to determine the document _type {:es_version=>7}
[2022-01-13T20:44:24,245][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][first-pip] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"https://logstash_writer:xxxxxx@x.x.x.x:9200/"}
[2022-01-13T20:44:24,247][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][second-pip] Restored connection to ES instance {:url=>"https://logstash_writer:xxxxxx@x.x.x.x:9200/"}
[2022-01-13T20:44:24,602][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][first-pip] Using a default mapping template {:es_version=>7, :ecs_compatibility=>:disabled}
[2022-01-13T20:44:24,606][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][second-pip] Using a default mapping template {:es_version=>7, :ecs_compatibility=>:disabled}
[2022-01-13T20:44:25,004][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][first-pip] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"first-pip", "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>1000, "pipeline.sources"=>["/etc/logstash/conf.d/file1.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x5fda836f@/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:125 run>"}
[2022-01-13T20:44:25,004][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][second-pip] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"second-pip", "pipeline.workers"=>8, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>1000, "pipeline.sources"=>["/etc/logstash/conf.d/file2.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x84fc1d4 run>"}
[2022-01-13T20:44:27,912][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][second-pip] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>2.9}
[2022-01-13T20:44:27,914][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][first-pip] Pipeline Java execution initialization time {"seconds"=>2.9}
[2022-01-13T20:44:28,025][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][second-pip] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"second-pip"}
[2022-01-13T20:44:28,026][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][first-pip] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"first-pip"}
```

the main problem is that when I run `systemctl start logstash`

it only execute the first one which is first-pip

I want to know how to synchronize schedules and pipelines to run in parallel.

Comment: You configuration seems to be already correct to do what you expect. Can you update your question with the at least the full `input` for your pipelines? Also, check logstash logs to see if there is something that can give a hint of the issue, share the logs after you start logstash.

Comment: I aggree with with @leandrojmp. With different pipelines, your configuration should be able to run in parallel. Check your cron configs. To run every 20th and every 30th minute of an hour you need */20 * * * *  and  */30 * * * *  respectively. 

With the above confg, if you run it e.g. at the 26th minute of an hour , it will run only [first-pip] and stop.

Comment: For logstash crons I suggest using https://crontab.guru/